# c++ getline and stringstream

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

I'm trying to read in a file, which has 5 lines, and every line is 3-4 string long.
Here's my input file:

```
10:30 Hurley 1234567A 10:15
10:45 Hurley 1234567A 11:30
08:35 Jacob 1x1x1x1x1x
08:35 Jacob 1x1x1x1x1x 08:10
08:05 Jacob 1x1x1x1x1x
08:45 Sayid 33332222 09:15
```

And this is what I get:

```
10:30 Hurley 1234567A   10:15
10:45 Hurley 1234567A   11:30
08:35 Jacob  1x1x1x1x1x 11:30
08:35 Jacob  1x1x1x1x1x 08:10
08:05 Jacob  1x1x1x1x1x 08:10
08:45 Sayid  33332222   09:15
```

This is my code:

```
void enor::Read(status &sx,isle &dx,ifstream &x){
    string str;
    getline(x, str, '\n');
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    ss >> dx.in >> dx.name >> dx.id >> dx.out;
    /*getline(x, str, '\n');
    x>>dx.in>>dx.name>>dx.id>>dx.out;*/
    if(x.fail())
        sx=abnorm;
    else
        sx=norm;
}
```

How can I read in the file without having the 3rd and 5th line filled with the 2nd and 4th line's time? I want the dx.out to be empty. Should I use another method, or is it possible to be done with stringstream?

Comment: Can you show how you're calling this function too? Are you reusing the `dx` object?

Comment: void enor::First(){
    Read(sx,dx,x);
    Next();
}

void enor::Next(){
    end=sx==abnorm;
    if(!end){
        current.in=dx.in;
        current.name=dx.name;
        current.id=dx.id;
        current.out=dx.out;
        Read(sx,dx,x);
        /*while(sx==norm && dx.id==current.id){
            if(dx.in>current.out)
                
                Read(sx,dx,x);
        }*/
    }
}

Answer (score 5):

If `>>` sees that there is nothing left in the `stringstream`, it will leave the variable untouched - so `dx.out` keeps its value from the last line. However, you can do

```
ss >> dx.in >> dx.name >> dx.id;
if (!(ss >> dx.out))
    dx.out = "";
```

because `ss >> dx.out` returns `ss`, and when a stream is converted to a `bool` (such as when it is used in an `if` condition), it returns `false` if the last read attempt failed.